# Need double quotes in $val field

Tags: php, arrays

We are creating a file such that when we execute the file we push an array into a new PHP file . 
We are able to print the array details in new PHP file but we are not able to get the double quotes for the $val fields .

Code is as follows

```
<?php
include_once("../dc/dcCommonLib.php");
include_once("../dc/persistence/UserData.php");
require_once("../../lib/include/connect.inc.php");

$_SESSION["survey"] = "BestBuyAug2012";
$idLink = dbconnect($_SESSION["survey"]);
$surveyWidget = rendererSurveyLoadHandler();
setDataToSession("surveywidget",$surveyWidget);
$userData = &UserData::getInstance();
$userData->setSurvey($surveyWidget);
saveFkidsToOidToFkidMappingArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping);

// prepare demo array
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Demographic"]["Q"],$demo,"b");

// prepare item array
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Default"]["Q"],$item,"i");
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Default"]["M"],$item,"i");

// prepare comment array
prepareCommentArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Comment"]["C"],$comment);


if (!function_exists('file_put_contents')) {
    /* ... define that function then ... */ 
}

print("Strart writting ...................");
file_put_contents("Test.php", $file,"",true);
file_put_contents("Test.php", "<?php\n","",true);
file_put_contents("Test.php", $item,"itemFkids",true);
file_put_contents("Test.php", $demo,"demoFkids",true);
file_put_contents("Test.php", $comment,"commentFkids",true);
file_put_contents("Test.php", "?>","",true);

print("written ...");

function prepareItemArray($userDataArray, &$item, $itemStr) {
    if(is_array($userDataArray)) {
        foreach($userDataArray as $questId=>$respGrp) {
            $selectionGrp=array_unique($respGrp);
            if(count($selectionGrp)==1) {
                $respGrpId=key($respGrp);
                $respId = key($respGrp[$respGrpId]);
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$itemStr.$respGrp[$respGrpId][$respId];           
            }else {
                foreach ($respGrp as $respGrpId=>$resp) {
                    $respGrp[$respGrpId]=$itemStr.$resp;
                }
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$respGrp;
            }
        }
    }   
}

function prepareCommentArray($userDataArray, &$item) {
    if(is_array($userDataArray)) {
        foreach($userDataArray as $questId=>$respGrp) {
            $selectionGrp=array_unique($respGrp);
            if(count($selectionGrp)==1) {
                $respGrpId=key($respGrp);               
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$respGrp[$respGrpId]["fk_id"];            
            }
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

the array that we get in Test.php is

```
<?php
$itemFkids = Array
(
    "203_19" => i27,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
    "207_22" => i28,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
    "357_22" => i99,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
    "370_70" => i104,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
    "377_72" => i105,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
)
$demoFkids = Array
(
    "129_2" => b1//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
)
$commentFkids = Array
(
    "373_375" => 1,//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
    "380_382" => 2//need double qoutes for all the $val fields
)
?>
```

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Please post a **consise** code snippet of the problem, don't throw your entire application at us. Give us the relevant piece of code where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Let me just edit my post

Comment: @Truth Does it make sense now >

Comment: @tigrang Sorry I did not get you

Comment: Why are you not simply using `var_export`?!

Comment: @deceze can we do it using var_export ?

Comment: Just use true for the second param so it returns instead of outputing, then write to your file.

Comment: @tigrang could you show me how its done ?

Comment: Replace `print_r` with `var_export` essentially

Comment: So you basically removed the interesting part of your code but left over the non-saying part. I rolled it back.

Comment: @hakre as truth said I just gave only the info which was needed . I thought that would be easier for the people who would help me

Comment: @hakre one more thing . I forgot to askhow to get a comma after the end of each array . should I post a new question again ? (p.s I am new to stack overflow so I do not know how things work here)

Comment: Well I think you are a bit too fast. Just relax. For example you accepted an answer that contains a variable (`$data`) that is not even part of your code. Also take a moment to think about what Deceeze answered: I bet you are not the first person who does what you do, so consider that a solution already exists. You only need to find out which one that is. So before you write a function your own, think practical.

Comment: @hakre the variable $data was in the question when i've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Replace `$data[$key] .= ',';` with `$data[$key] .= '",';`</s>

Edit:

```
$data[$key] = '"'.$data[$key].'",';
```

Comment: I wish it was so simple my friend . I need double qoutes on both sides of the $val . Example 
    "207_22" => "i28",
    "357_22" => "i99",

Comment: That worked perfectly fine . For some reason this did not flash me . Thank you very much

Comment: How do I get a comma at the end of each array ?

Answer (score 3):

> `var_export`
>
> `var_export()` gets structured information about the given variable. It is similar to `var_dump()` with one exception: ***the returned representation is valid PHP code.***
>
> http://php.net/var_export

(Highlight mine.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking for, but as far as I can understand you want to add double quotes around the array values .

The only way of doing this is by adding them in the code as part of the value.  here are some test cases you can try for your self :

```
<?php 
    $value_3 = 'value_3';

    $data = array( 'key_1' => 'value_1' // value without quotes
                  ,'key_2' => '"value_2"' // value with quotes
                  ,'key_3' => '"'.$value_3.'"' // adding quotes to value
    );

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```

if you not want to mess with your existing code to much you can also loop over the array in the end and add the double quotes then :

```
<?php 
    foreach( $data AS $key => $value ){
        $data[$key] = '"'.trim( $value, '"').'"'; // add double quotes to all values
    }

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Yes . I do not want to change my code . Let me just try it . Thank you . Will be back in 15mins .